# Read csv file with Java OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I have the following .csv file:

```
Company ABC                             
"Jan 1, 2020 - Sep 30, 2020"                                
Product Country Avg. monthly clients    Avg. month charge   Parts change    Impact  In stock    Clients in list City
Nissan Maxima   USA 6600    0%  -18%    Low 18      
BMW X7 M50i USA 18100   22% 0%  Low 28      
Volvo XC90  USA 880 0%  -12%    Low 10      
Opel Insignia   USA 320 -34%    -34%    Low 23      
Renult Triber   USA 140 -18%    -36%    Low 8       
Toyota Yaris    USA 880 0%  -28%    Low 30      
Ford Mondeo USA 70  -20%    -71%    Low 1
```

for delimiter I have empty space(Tab). I tried to use this code in order to read the file using Opencsv:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CsvLine {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String model;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private String country;
}

            String fileName = "C:\\in_progress\\zzz.csv";

            List<CsvLine> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader(fileName))
                    .withType(CsvLine.class)
                    .withSeparator(' ')
                    .withSkipLines(1)
                    .build()
                    .parse();

            for(CsvLine item: beans){
                System.out.println(item.getModel());
            }
```

But I get this output:

```
 X C 9 0 
null
 I n s i g n i a     U S A   3 2 0   - 3 4 %     - 3 4 %     L o w   2 3         
null
 T r i b e r 
null
 Y a r i s   U S A   8 8 0   0 %     - 2 8 %     L o w   3 0         
null
 M o n d e o     U S A   7 0     - 2 0 %     - 7 1 %     L o w   1       
null
null
```

Do you know how I can the file properly with Java preferably with OpenCSV?

Test file https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jo4i3bs6h8at25/zzz.csv?dl=0

Comment: The header of your csv file looks incorrect - maybe it is causing the issue

Comment: The output does not match the code you have quoted. Also - the CSV file is invalid, as it is using the separator char (" ") in the field values.

What does "for delimiter I have empty space(Tab)" actually mean? Tab and Space are two different things.

Comment: You should provide your CSV file.

Comment: I added test file link.

Comment: The file is encoded in UTF-16, which explains the issue.

Comment: How I can read it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSV file really uses the Tab character as field delimitier, it should be sufficient to change to:

```java
            List<CsvLine> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader(fileName))
                    .withType(CsvLine.class)
                    .withSeparator('\t')
                    .withSkipLines(2)
                    .build()
                    .parse();
```

I changed `withSeparator` argument and increased the number of lines to skip to 2

Comment: The code works but I get a text with empty spaces like this for example: ` O p e l   I n s i g n i a ` Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Why should we guess? Why don't you provide your file instead?

Comment: @Olivier here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jo4i3bs6h8at25/zzz.csv?dl=0  Please try it.

Comment: @PeterPenzov The file is encoded in UTF-16.